# How to group checkboxes to restrict selection to a single option?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I'm trying to set up two check box's in a DataGrid so that only one can be checked at any one time.

At the moment, the following renders the existing state of the choice on screen:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Choice One">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxChoiceOne" 
                      CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ChoiceOne") %>'
                     runat="server">
        </asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Choice Two">
    <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxChoiceTwo" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ChoiceTwo") %>'
                        runat="server">
          </asp:CheckBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

How do I go about ensuring that if the user chooses ChoiceOne that any selection of ChoiceTwo will be unselected and vice versa? Is there any way to state in the DataGrid control that these two checkboxes are grouped together?

Comment: That's what Radio buttons are for.  They are exclusive.  Can you use those instead?

Comment: +1 Post that as an answer and it should be accepted

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a situation for Radio Buttons instead of checkboxes. You are violating user expectations if you have checkboxes behave in that manner. From a UI perspective that isn't a great idea.

Comment: And if min zero selection and maximum one selection will be required then what would be the solution??

Answer (score 0):

You should use radio buttons for this purpose.